# Setting a limit to an int value

Tags: java, math, int, limit

I want to set a limit to an `int` value I have in Java. I'm creating a simple health system, and I want my health to stay between 0 and 100. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to set a limit?

Comment: I don't want my health to go beneath 0, or above 100.

Comment: I'm guessing you want something a little more complicated than `yourInt=Math.max(yourInt, 100);` , so please can you elaborate a little more on the question?

Comment: Well either check for boundaries when you get input or create a special `healtInt` class to do it for you.

Comment: Why would it go beyond those limits?

Comment: Well, because I didn't made it so it didn't go under 0 or above 100 yet? But, my question has been answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - limit number between min and max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933493/java-limit-number-between-min-and-max)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a class called Health and you check every time if a new value is set if it fulfills the constraints :

```
public class Health {

   private int value;

   public Health(int value) {
      if (value < 0 || value > 100) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      } else {
         this.value = value;
      }
   }

   public int getHealthValue() {
      return value;
   }


   public void setHealthValue(int newValue) {
    if (newValue < 0 || newValue > 100) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      } else {
      value = newValue;
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked out exactly the way I wanted. (Can't click the accept button yet, have to wait 6 more minutes.)

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is what you typically want to use for illegal arguments like this. Methods that model the things you want to do in a game (like adding or removing X health without going beyond the boundaries) are key on a class like this too.

Comment: Yes you could also use IllegalArgumentException instead of a custom HelathException.

Comment: I would use the setHeathValue within the Constructor so it doesn't have to be wrote twice, but besides that, its all good.

Comment: I wouldn't do that since you shouldn't call overridable methods in the constructor.

Comment: now you can refactor this so the "if" part is extracted to external method. DRY :)

Comment: also, I would do renaming work here: variable "value" to "health" and do appropriate renaming with setter and getter.

Answer (score 6):

Use a getter/setter model.

```
public class MyClass{
    private int health;

    public int getHealth(){
        return this.health;
    }

    public int setHealth(int health){
        if(health < 0 || health > 100){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Health must be between 0 and 100, inclusive");
        }else{
            this.health = health;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a class that enforces that.

```
public class Health {
  private int health = 100;

  public int getHealth() {
    return health;
  }

  // use this for gaining health
  public void addHealth(int amount) {
    health = Math.min(health + amount, 100);
  }

  // use this for taking damage, etc.
  public void removeHealth(int amount) {
    health = Math.max(health - amount, 0);
  }

  // use this when you need to set a specific health amount for some reason
  public void setHealth(int health) {
    if (health < 0 || health > 100)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Health must be in the range 0-100: " + health);
    this.health = health;
  }
}
```

This way if you have an instance of `Health`, you know for a fact that it represents a valid amount of health. I imagine that you'd typically want to just use methods like `addHealth` rather than setting the health directly.

Answer (score 1):

encapsulate the field and put a check in setter method.

```
int a;

void setA(int a){
   if value not in range throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit a primitive in Java. The only thing you can do is to write a wrapper class for this. Of course by doing this you lose the nice operator support and have to use methods (like `BigInteger`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setHealth(int newHealth) {
  if(newHealth >= 0 && newHealth <= 100) {
    _health = newHealth;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

No point in creating a special class.
To increment i, use this:

public void specialIncrement(int i)
{
   if(i<100)
      i++
}

Comment: How should this answer the question?

Comment: Doesn't really enforce it as it would be all too easy to forget and increment i without using the specialincrementer.