# Java - limit number between min and max

Tags: java, range, max, min, clamp

I want to return the number as long as it falls within a limit, else return the maximum or minimum value of the limit. I can do this with a combination of `Math.min` and `Math.max`.

```
public int limit(int value) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(value, 10));
}
```

I'm wondering if there's an existing `limit` or `range` function I'm overlooking.
3rd party libraries welcome if they are pretty common (eg: Commons or Guava)

Comment: Why is this necessary if `Math.min` `Math.max` provides your solution?

Comment: That is the appropriate pattern.  If you do this in a lot of places, just define your own method in a helper class.

Comment: If this code seems too long, just wrap it in your own function.

Comment: I'm coming to the community to see if such a function already exists. Just a question.. I don't think it's a bad question?

Comment: It's a rather trivial question, but nobody has voted to close it yet.

Comment: Not a bad question.  You show what have done so far and you ask specifically if there is a one method solution.  No one wants to appear ignorant by reinventing the wheel when a simpler solution exists.  Not sure why it was downvoted, but I +1'ed to help counter it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was wondering the same thing.  It seems really straightforward.  I guess it's a just something mathematicians would expect to be already built in the math library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is new [`Math.clamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#clamp(long,int,int)) method (with multiple overloads) added in Java 21 to conveniently clamp the numeric value between the specified minimum and maximum values:

```
int valueToClamp = 0;

System.out.println(Math.clamp(valueToClamp, 1, 10)); // 1
```

`public static int clamp(long value, int min, int max)`

- `value` - value to clamp
- `min` - minimal allowed value
- `max` - maximal allowed value

Answer (score 33):

OP asks for this implementation in a standard library:

```
int ensureRange(int value, int min, int max) {
   return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}

boolean inRange(int value, int min, int max) {
   return (value>= min) && (value<= max);
}
```

A pity the standard Math library lacks these

Comment: Also, the C-based languages lack the obvious idiom `(min <= value <= max)`, much to the consternation of newbies.

Comment: I think that ensureRange should be other way around:

`int ensureRange(int value, int min, int max) {
        return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
    }`

That's a good reason to have it in a library. So you can have it wrong only once ;-)

Comment: @RensoLohuis Trivial: I wanted `min` executed before `max`. Read order != Execution order.

Comment: @BarryStaes I am not talking about execution order. You have Math.min(value, min), this will not help you to ensure the range. if the value = 3 and min = 5, Math.min will return 3, so it will not stay inside range. The same goes for Math.max(value, max). So this function will not ensure range.

Comment: @RensoLohuis thanks good catch! Pardon my brainfart, fixed now.

Answer (score 19):

I understand this was asked for Java. In Android world, it's common to use Kotlin 
and Java combined. In case some Kotlin user reached here (just like me), then they can use `coerceIn` extension function:

Kotlin Code:

```
println(10.coerceIn(1, 100)) // 10
println(10.coerceIn(1..100)) // 10
println(0.coerceIn(1, 100)) // 1
println(500.coerceIn(1, 100)) // 100
```

Read more on official [Kotlin Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/coerce-in.html).

Answer (score 15):

As of version 21, [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) includes [`Ints.constrainToRange()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#constrainToRange-int-int-int-) (and equivalent methods for the other primitives). From the [release notes](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21#commonprimitives):

> added `constrainToRange([type] value, [type] min, [type] max)` methods which constrain the given value to the closed range defined by the `min` and `max` values. They return the value itself if it's within the range, the `min` if it's below the range and the `max` if it's above the range.

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42968254/122441 by @dimo414.

Unfortunately this version is quite recent as of July 2017, and in some projects (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40691831/122441) Guava had broken backwards compatibility that required me to stay on version 19 for now. I'm also shocked that neither Commons Lang nor Commons Math has it! :(

Answer (score 13):

If you're on Android, use the MathUtils (in support library), it has only one function which specifically does this called clamp.

> This method takes a numerical value and ensures it fits in a given
>   numerical range. If the number is smaller than the minimum required by
>   the range, then the minimum of the range will be returned. If the
>   number is higher than the maximum allowed by the range then the
>   maximum of the range will be returned.

Comment: great. just for the record, a usage example: `MathUtils.clamp( value, min, max )`

Answer (score 5):

The `Math.max(int a, int b)` function is defined as:

```
public static int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

So you can make a combination of the `max` and `min` functions as follows:

```
private static int MAX=10;
private static int MIN=0;

public int limit(int a) {
    return (a > MAX) ? MAX : (a < MIN ? MIN: a );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Generic method for any class implementing `Comparable` (including `Number` and its sub-classes):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T limit(T o, T min, T max){
    if (o.compareTo(min) < 0) return min;
    if (o.compareTo(max) > 0) return max;
    return o;
}
```

The only requirement is that **all arguments must be of the same class**. It prevents possible type conversion loss.
 In fact it is incorrect to compare `float` with `double` of `long` with `int` etc. For example `(double) 0.1 != (float) 0.1`.

**Usage:**

```
double x = 13.000000001;
x = limit(x, 12.0, 13.0);
System.out.println("x = " + x); //x = 13.0
```

Unfortunately it is impossible to change the first argument directly by just `limit(x, 12.0, 13.0)` because primitive types are immutable.

Answer (score -6):

You do not need an external library for this, try this test case:

```java
public class RandomNumber {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        System.out.println("random = " + randomInRange(5,10));
    }
    
    public static double randomInRange(double arg1, double arg2) {
        double my_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (arg1 - arg2) + arg2);
        return my_number;
    }

}
```