# Limit the range of an integer in Java

Tags: java, int, limit

Is it possible to limit the range of a number as in for example:
x to be between 0 and 24,if x drops to -1 he would instead become 24,-2 would be 23 and the same with 25 - > 0 ,26 -> 1.

Comment: You can do that manually, with a custom class (maybe extending `Number` too).

Comment: check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933493/java-limit-number-between-min-and-max

Answer (score 1):

Use somehting like

```
  class BoundedInteger {

private static final int MAX_VALUE = 25;
private int value;

BoundedInteger(int value) {
    value %= MAX_VALUE;
    if (value < 0)
        value = MAX_VALUE - Math.abs(value);
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value % MAX_VALUE;
  }
}
```