# Is there function in java restrict component move only in Frame?

Tags: java, swing, frame

I tried to Find API that restrict component's movable area only in inside of Frame. Is there such API?

I guess such function is located in category of JFrame. but actually there are almost things about making components of Swing. I also searched API of SwingUtilities, but i think there are no useful API related to my problem.

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Point MousePoint=arg0.getPoint();
    label.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    label.setLocation(MousePoint);
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    label.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    label.setLocation(getLocationOnScreen());
}
```

I expected using setBounds() will restrict movable area in Frame. but when i drag label over area of Frame, it was find that label move along.

Comment: Please post [mcve] of what you tried

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would add a `ComponentListener` to the `label` and implement the `componentMoved` method.
In that method you can then add checks, whether the component still is in bounds and set the location correspondingly:

```
label.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        int newX = label.getX();
        int newY = label.getY();

        if(label.getX() < 0) {
            newX = 0;
        } else if(label.getX() + label.getWidth() > contentPane.getWidth()) {
            newX = contentPane.getWidth() - label.getWidth();
        }

        if(label.getY() < 0) {
            newY = 0;
        } else if(label.getY() + label.getHeight() > contentPane.getHeight()) {
            newY = contentPane.getHeight() - label.getHeight();
        }

        label.setLocation(newX, newY);
    }
});
```

This solution works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple `if` checks inside your `mouseDragged` and `mouseReleased` methods to keep the arguments for your `setBounds/setLocation` call inside a given range. You can use some example from [Java - limit number between min and max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933493/java-limit-number-between-min-and-max) to keep the numbers between `0` and "width/height of panel/canvas" like:

> ```
> int ensureRange(int value, int min, int max) {
>     return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
> }
> ```

You need to calculate the possible min and max values first. After that use these new values for the new bounds/location. The code might be looking like this (pseudo code):

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    Point mousePoint=arg0.getPoint();

    int x = ensureRange(mousePoint.x, 0, c.getWidth());
    int y = ensureRange(mousePoint.y, 0, c.getHeight());

    Point newPoint = new Point(x, y);

    label.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    label.setLocation(newPoint);
}
```

You might need to adjust the limits based on your code.